# PDFTron - HTML2PDF - Operation file seek failed

Tags: java, pdftron

While converting bulk html files to pdf, getting Conversion failed error. For same html file sometimes it work. Mainly whenever more files are there one or two get failed.

PdfTron Version : September 2016,
Environment : Linux, Java 8

Followed this article, https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/HTML2PDFTest.java.html

```
String inputHtml = "/myfolder/output.html";
String outputPdf = "/myfolder/output.pdf";
PDFNet.initialize();
PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc();
HTML2PDF converter = new HTML2PDF();
converter.setLandscape(false);
converter.setPaperSize(9);
converter.insertFromHtmlString(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputHtml))));
if (converter.convert(doc)) {
    doc.initSecurityHandler();
    doc.save(outputPdf, SDFDoc.e_linearized, null);
} else {
    log.error("Conversion failed. HTTP Code: " + converter.getHTTPErrorCode() + "\n" + converter.getLog());
}
```

**Output**

```
Conversion failed. HTTP Code: 0
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[=================>                                          ] 29%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
[=====================>                                      ] 36%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[==============================>                             ] Page 1 of 2
[============================================================] Page 2 of 2
Done                                                                      
Post Process Error: Operation file seek failed
StdFile.cpp:478
DataWrite
```

Comment: are you rewriting the file at path `\myfolder\output.pdf`?

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui, No I am not /myfolder/output.pdf only for example. I am using new file name with unique id every time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is some read/write permission issue with the temp folder being used.

Please try the following.

```
PDFNet.setTempPath(folder_that_you_know_your_process_can_read_write);
PDFNet.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can't use simple backslashes in strings representing a path. The string `"\myfolder\output.pdf"` is equal to `"myfolderoutput.pdf"`. Either use double backslashes (\) or forward slashes (/)

Comment: Sorry, completely ignore that backslashes ie typo. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding executable permission on lib files present in HTML2PDF module worked for me(on macos)

```
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/html2pdf_chromium.dylib 
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/libswiftshader_libEGL.dylib
```